# Redraw customized UIButton after click

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a customized UIButton that I want to redraw after it is clicked -- I want to change its color. Here is the code:

```
class DayButtons: UIButton {

    var isPressed: Bool = false

    var color = UIColor.whiteColor()

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let cornerR = CGFloat(5)       
        var path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerR)
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Is there way to call drawRect again in my main thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call `setNeedsDisplay()` on your button, which will in turn call `drawRect()` for you.

Comment: alternatively, can i use init to set the background color and change it in my viewcontoller? which way is better?

Comment: never mind, it worked, i'm sticking with it. thanks!

Comment: I was answering the question, "is there a way to call `drawRect` again?" If you want to change your approach, that works too – unless you've posted only a portion of your code, what you're trying to do is trivial without custom drawing. Give your button a background colour, then adjust its `layer.cornerRadius` property to suit.